# Optirun command stops working on Optimus system after some time

Tags: debian, nvidia, bumblebee, optimus

I need to run CUDA enabled applications, but (because of other things) I'd rather use Optimus technology rather than running on Nvidia card only. Note that for CUDA I need to use proprietary binary nvidia drivers.

I followed: https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee this tutorial (and setup is mostly working). After reboot I can successfully run `optirun something` command. But after some time I get:

```
 optirun deviceQuery 
 [ 4574.136296] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card
 [ 4574.136358] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I use Quadro K2000M:

```
  lspci -k 
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] (rev ff)
  Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Here are my questions:

- Does anyone have pointers how to solve this problem on debian.
- Is there any guide on manually restarting nvidia card using bbswitch?
- How can I disable bbswitch at all (losing power management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested: I have solved this problem by ditching Optimus altogether and just running on proprietary nVidia drivers. Before that I enabled only nVidia card in BIOS).